# Using ManifestMerger to remove am activity component

Tags: android, gradle, android-manifest

Can anyone show me how to remove an activity component that has an intent filter with ManifestMerger?

I have in my `main`'s `AndroidManifest.xml` this:

```
<activity android:name=".GoodActivity">
    <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="open.good.activity"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

In another flavor's `AndroidManifest.xml`, I have:

```
<activity
    android:name=".GoodActivity"
    tools:node="remove"/>
```

But I can see that in the generated, merged `AndroidManifest.xml`, the activity is still present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I just just need to enclose `<activity>` in an `<application>` tag just like I normally do in an `AndroidManifest.xml`.

So, in the flavor's `AndroidManifest.xml`, I should have:

```
<application>
    <activity
        android:name=".GoodActivity"
        tools:node="remove"/>
</application>
```